# How to configure routes in Ubuntu in order to use network card just in local network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, network-adapter

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with two network cards. Because of the security of my organization, I need to use one to connected it to the traffic within a network 10.*.*.*, and the other one to have internet access.

If I open network manager and select "Use this connection only for resources in your network" everyting goes fine... until...

My IP in that server is 10.5.24.* so if someone with the IP 10.5.*.* tries to connect to the server, it won't answer, cause that network can only be reached if you have one ip within 10.5. How can I add one route in the network manager to answer to 10.*.*.*?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**

@david-go This is my current configuration:

```
IP Address: 10.58.24.35
Broadcast: 10.58.31.255
Subnet Mask: 255.255.248.0
Gateway: 10.58.24.1
DNS: 10.58.8.101
```

If I checked the checkbox "Use this connection only for resources in your network" everyone in the network 10.58.24.* can reach the server, but the problem is when someone in the network, for example: 10.58.7.* tries to see it. As "my network" is 10.58.24.* then the server does not answer the request.

**EDIT 2**

Info: from `(/sbin/ifconfig;/sbin/route -n)`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 18:03:73:d6:f8:bf  
          Direc. inet:10.58.24.35  Difus.:10.58.31.255  Másc:255.255.248.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::1a03:73ff:fed6:f8bf/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:4643576 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:1981118 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:1035692649 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:1286344748 (1.2 GB)
          Interrupción:20 Memoria:e1a00000-e1a20000 

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:876450 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:876450 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:136458162 (136.4 MB)  TX bytes:136458162 (136.4 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:14:d1:21:a7:73  
          Direc. inet:172.16.115.133  Difus.:172.16.119.255  Másc:255.255.248.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::214:d1ff:fe21:a773/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:64840 errores:0 perdidos:113 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:880 errores:0 perdidos:6 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:9839656 (9.8 MB)  TX bytes:195993 (195.9 KB)

Tabla de rutas IP del núcleo
Destino         Pasarela        Genmask         Indic Métric Ref    Uso Interfaz
0.0.0.0         172.16.112.6    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.58.24.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.16.112.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

**EDIT 3**

This is the result for lspci:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
**00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)**
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

And lsusb

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
**Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter**
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp.
```

Comment: To help solve your problem you really need to provide more in-depth information (particularly the IP addresses and network setup).  It sounds like you need to do source-based routing - which is a bit of a pain - but it might well be that there are other solutions - but we don't know untul you know your setup.

Comment: @davidgo I already added the information.

Comment: Please can you add the output of "/sbin/ifconfig" and "/sbin/route -n", as I'm still unclear what you are saying and how your computer is behaving.  (You can get create a file with this information by opening a terminal window and typing "(/sbin/ifconfig;/sbin/route -n) > filename.txt" which will store the info I need in a file you can copy and paste or upload.

Comment: @davidgo Done! It is the result of (/sbin/ifconfig;/sbin/route -n)

Comment: I still don't fully understand how things should be working, but I can see that you only have 1 Network card (eth0) configured.  I think the solution will be to configure the second network card on the 10.5.24 network.  I have no idea how you would do this through a GUI (but I can do it through startup scripts or terminal commands).  Do you know for sure if your second network card is eth1, and if that card is actually working ?  (There is no indication of it in your output)

Comment: My second card is wlan0, for some reason when I ran that script it was disconnected. @davidgo I've updated the information to add the wlan0 configuration.

Comment: @davidgo, question: Will that work if I change the subnet mask from 255.255.248.0 to something like 255.0.0.0? I don't fully understand how this works, but I'm supposing in that way the network card will be able to connect to 10.*.*.*... am I right?

Comment: No, this is unlikely.  Are you aware that WLAN0 is almost certainly wifi card, not a regular Network card ?  Using a bigger netmask will not work properly. Do you want to move this to a chat so we can interact to solve the problem in real time ? (I am at GMT+13, so timing might be interesting).

Comment: Can you advise - 1.  How many physical network cards you think you have ?  2. What devices your physical network cards connect to ? 3. The output of "lspci" ?  (lspci will tell us what devices your computer thinks are physically installed)

Comment: I KNOW I have only one physical network card (I have the CPU next to me). I've added the output for lspci and lsusb, and marked with ** the 2 network cards (as u can see one ethernet and the other wireless) I have. With the wireless I have internet access, and with the other one I have access to my network resources, so I want to use the ethernet for all the resources at 10.*.*.* and the wireless for everything outside it.

Comment: I still don't understand how your addressing works - ie why your WIFI device is in the 172 netblock, but based on what you have said, yes, decreasing your netmask on 255.0.0.0 will make everythin in 10.x.x.x directly reachable over your wifi interface, so if your server is on the same subnet (ie you don't need to go through a router to reach it) it will work.  It now seems that you may need some static routes.   Can you provide a diagram of some sort showing how your network looks (including devices and IP addresses for each interface on relevant devices, and where Internet plugs in)

Comment: I can't cause I don't know. Wifi has that IP cause it is a totally different network, through which I have internet access. I'm not the guy in charge of the network...

Comment: @davidgo For what I understand, I need to add routes. So the question is may be: how can I add a route to all the traffic from 10.*.*.* go through eth0? I tried this: `route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.0 eth0` but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to accomplished this. I've to add to routes:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.58.24.1 eth0
```

That make everything in 10.0.0.0 go through `eth0`; and:

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 172.16.112.6 wlan0
```

That makes everything else go through `wlan0`

Comment: Thx, you saved my life :-).